# Wordpress cache of comments

Tags: wordpress

I have a plain php script that changes some fields on comment table. Fields like status or text of the comment.

Everything works well as long as I am logged as I admin: the comment are shown with the changes made in the plain php script. As a guest, no change is shown, it looks like there a cache page shown.

Question: is there a way I can invalidate cache problematically as long I make changes on mysql table? Do I have to change some specific fields on that table?

Comment: Do you have some sort of caching plugin enabled?

Comment: yes, wp-super-cache plugin.

Comment: Most likely there's a setting for the plugin that disables the site cache for logged in admin users, switch that off to see what your users are seeing.